# An open set in $\mathbb{A}^1$ isomorphic to $V(XY-1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question was part of my assignment in Algebraic geometry and I am not able to prove the required assertion.  I am following the textbook by Daniel Perrin.

Question:  Let Y be an algebraic subset such that  $Y= V(XY-1) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$. Prove that there exists an open set $U\subset \mathbb{A}^1$ and an isomorphism $U\approx Y$ and find the open set $U$.

I am very sorry but I am not able to find such an open set or why such an isomorphism must exist.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you know what are the open subsets of affine line (in Zariski topology) and can you describe rings of regular functions on them?

Comment: Please pick more informative titles. E.g. "An open set in $\mathbb{A}^1$ isomorphic to $V(XY-1)$"

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you very much! I have edited the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the hyperbola defined by $xy-1=0$ over the reals (i.e. in $\Bbb{A}^2_{\Bbb{R}})$ - in fact, you might want to look at a graph. What happens when you apply the projection map $\Bbb{A}^2_{\Bbb{R}}\to \Bbb{A}^1_{\Bbb{R}}$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x$?

This will suggest for you what the map should be, and what the open in $\Bbb{A}^1$ ought to be. Notice that this all makes sense over any field $k$ (except perhaps the graphical representation).

Comment: I have understood your 1st paragraph but still I am not able to find the map. I think  in $\mathbb{A}^1$ the closed sets are with finite elements as the topology is cofinite topology. I request you to write an answer instead of just hints.

Comment: Dear DTPW, I think you should try to work it out yourself. The hint is fairly generous, I think. Consider what the image of the projection map is in $\Bbb{A}^1$...

Comment: Dear Alekos, I think when I apply the projection I get the set {y=0 }/{(0,0)}. The open in $\mathbb{A}^1$ I have already defined in my 1st comment.

Comment: Yes, the open set you get by projection is $\Bbb{A}^1$ with the origin removed. Let's write it as $U$. This gives an algebraic map $V(xy-1) \to U$. Can you find an inverse map? I claim it should be clear from the picture (or from algebra if not).

Comment: Great. Nice work.

Comment: I was having same problem and found this post. What do you mean by algebraic map

Comment: You could define it a few ways. Let's say that it means a map whose component functions are given by rational functions.

Comment: What kind of isomorphism are we looking for ? K-algebra isomorphism right?

Comment: Here we are working in the category of varieties over $k$. Of course, it is equivalent to the dual statement that there should be an isomorphism of $k$-algebras of the coordinate rings. However, you don't really need to use that here. It suffices to construct a pair of mutually inverse maps of varieties.